# Python: replace a value in specific column in csv

Tags: python

please help on my below challenge, that i want to replace a value in specific column (comma separated data) when a match is found.

`file.csv` contains the number of rows, with a comma separated values. Using below, FOR each row, i look for first column field, and second column field.

```
if column1 filed == column2 field -->Delete first 2 fields, and write that row lines in column1 named file. 
if column1 filed != column2 field -->Delete first 2 fields, and write that row lines in separate two files. (column1 named file and column2 named file)
if column1 filed = empty, but column2 field exist -->Delete first 2 fields, and write that row lines in column2 named file, and vice versa.
```

my challenge is, before writing the file, i need to change the `column5` value to `column0/1' based on below condition.

```
import datetime
import os, csv
Y = open('file.csv', "r").readlines()
timestamp = '_' + '{:%Y%m%d%H%M%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())
for x in Y:
    csvdata = x.split(",")
    up = ','.join(csvdata[2:]) ######THIS DELETE FIRST 2 FIELDS
    if csvdata[0] == csvdata[1]:
        with open(csvdata[0] + timestamp + '.csv', 'a') as f:
            f.write(up)
            f.close()
    elif csvdata[0] != csvdata[1] and csvdata[1] != '' and csvdata[0] != '':
        with open(csvdata[0] + timestamp + '.csv', 'a') as f:
            f.write(up)
            f.close()
        with open(csvdata[1] + timestamp + '.csv', 'a') as f:
            f.write(up)
            f.close()
    elif csvdata[1] != '' and csvdata[0] == '':
        with open(csvdata[1] + timestamp + '.csv', 'a') as f:
            f.write(up)
            f.close()
    elif csvdata[0] != '' and csvdata[1] == '':
        with open(csvdata[0] + timestamp + '.csv', 'a') as f:
            f.write(up)
            f.close()
```

file.csv

```
apple,orange,0,1,orange,30 --> goes to BOTH apple, orange files(with replacement of 5th field)
apple,'',0,2,orange,30 ---> goes to apple file (with replacement of 5th field orange to apple)
'',orange,0,3,apple,30 ---> goes to orange file (with replacement of 5th field apple to orange)
apple,apple,0,4,orange,30 ---> goes to apple file (with replacement of 5th field orange to apple)
orange,orange,0,5,apple,30 ---> goes to orange file (with replacement of 5th field apple to orange)
```

expected output:

```
apple_20200402134567.csv
0,1,apple,30
0,2,apple,30
0,4,apple,30

orange_20200402134567.csv
0,1,orange,30
0,3,orange,30
0,5,orange,30
```

Please help how to add piece of code in above to replace 5th field based on match/condition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you describe what you have tried and what the output of those attempts have been? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Have a look into using a `pandas.DataFrame` for reading / manipulating your CSV file.  The [docs are here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code uses the csv import to read and write the files.  This ensures that the empty column fields `''` are empty strings.  Instead of the if/elif sequence, it uses a python set to determine the relevant file names to write. If there are many lines, the "open file/append a line/close file" is inefficient.  It would better to either use a dictionary to cache the csv.writer objects or accumulate all the rows in memory and then write all the files at the end.

```
import datetime
import csv

timestamp = '{:%Y%m%d%H%M%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())
with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quotechar="'")
  for row in reader:
    names = set(i for i in row[0:2] if i)
    for name in names:
      with open('{}-{}.csv'.format(name,timestamp), 'a') as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output, quotechar="'")
        row[4] = name
        writer.writerow(row[2:])
```

Comment: Hi Vincent,, thanks a lot.. it perfectly suits.. i am writing this if..else. for years.. set() has done magic here..

Comment: Though output is as expected, i could see a empty line after each line in output files, Could you please help how to get rid of that.

Comment: Please ignore. i have added , newline='' while opening csv file, and empty lines issue got resolved.. THANKS A LOT